# Try to send html from controller Laravel and data tables

Tags: php, html, laravel, yajra-datatable

#### Summary of problem or feature request

I want send to the table some HTML tags like

I use editColumn to add some HTML code to this column

its work with `addColumn` but not with `editColumn`

the question is how I can send HTML elements to table from controller the example above didn't show the HTML tags when I need to view label

#### Code snippet of problem

```
 public function CustomerTicketAjax(Request $request, $id){

    $tickets = Customer::find($id);
    return Datatables::of(CustomerTicket::with('user')->where('customer_id', $tickets->id))

        ->editColumn('status', function ($tickets) {
            if ($tickets->status == 1) {
                return '<span class="label bg-red" style="font-size: 21px;">open</span>';
            } elseif ($tickets->status == 0) {
                return '<span class="label bg-red" style="font-size: 21px;">close</span>';
            };
        })

        ->make(true);}
```

#### System details

- MAC OSX
- PHP 7.1
- Laravel 5.4
- Laravel-Datatables 7.*

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
return Response::json(array('element' => View::make('MyView')->render());
```